# Java Swing Gridbag panel wont colspan

Tags: java, swing, html-table, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

As far as i am aware the Swing Gridbag.gridwidth = 2; should work exactly as colspan does in HTML, that being force a column to stretch across providing one column that seperates into two on the next line etc

However mine appears to be compressing the two columns underneath it into one forcing them on top of each other.

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    new MainClass();

}

public MainClass() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

    final JTextField nameInput = new JTextField();

    final JLabel headerImage = new JLabel("test");

    final JTextField volunteerID = new JTextField();

    TitledBorder nameLabel;
    nameLabel = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Name");
    nameInput.setBorder(nameLabel);

    TitledBorder fileNameLabel;
    fileNameLabel = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Volunteer ID/ FileName");
    volunteerID.setBorder(fileNameLabel);


    JPanel constructorPanel = new JPanel();
    constructorPanel.add(nameInput);

    JPanel resultsPanel = new JPanel();
    resultsPanel.add(volunteerID);

    JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
    imagePanel.add(headerImage);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    // Constructors

    [[additional code]] //see below

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(constructorPanel, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    panel.add(resultsPanel, gbc);


    nameInput.setColumns(15);
    volunteerID.setColumns(15);

    this.pack();
    this.setTitle("GiGgle Pics Settings Constructor");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

}

The above produces the following:

[image]

However when I add following code in the space marked [[additional code]] above

```
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = WIDTH;
        panel.add(imagePanel, gbc);
```

I get this:

[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Removed as much code as I can

Comment: Please *read* the linked article (as opposed to guessing its meaning, or just glancing at it).  My point was not to make it shorter, but the other parts..

Comment: `gridwidth = 2` only means the component *can* use two columns, it doesn't necessarily mean it fills them. You need to also set `weightx = 1.0` and `fill = HORIZONTAL` in order for the component to actually *use* the available space.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the comment but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it,

The order in which i was adding components to the GridBagLayout was betting it up

```
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(constructorPanel, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    panel.add(resultsPanel, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(imagePanel, gbc);
```

By adding the colspan gbc at the bottom it ensures that its settings arn't also transferred to the others.

Another solution would be to reset the gbc.gridwidth = 2; on each

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)